# How to get comma values and remove null zero and space from SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Follwing below table to get comma value

Table Name IdsList

```
 Name  Aid    BId    CId   DId
 raj    1      Null    0    2
 ch     4      3       1    0
```

I need output from above table data like below remove the null 0 and space value

```
commavalue
 1,2
 4,3,1
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? What have you tried already? Can you provide [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info)?

Comment: it should work all version because local version is different and production version is different from my side. @ZoharPeled

Comment: Even if prod is a different version than your local copy knowing the version is important here. There are LOTS of versions of sql server.

Comment: What's the lowest version you need to support? I doubt you're going to need a solution for SQL Server 2000 version

Comment: This is probably better handled in the client code or reporting tool.

Comment: local version sql: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) and production version Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onward.

Notable points:

- The `CROSS APPLY` clause is converting all columns to XML data type, and
  automatically filtering out columns with NULL values.
- The XPath predicate `*[local-name()=("Aid","BId","CId","DId")]` will process all relevant columns. Very flexible.
- The 2nd XPath predicate [text()!="0"] is filtering out zero values.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20), Aid INT, BId INT, CId INT, DId INT);
INSERT @tbl (Name, Aid, BId, CId, DId) VALUES
('raj', 1, Null, 0, 2),
('ch ', 4, 3   , 1, 0);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/*[local-name()=("Aid","BId","CId","DId")][text()!="0"])')
        .value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), ',') AS commavalue
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| Name | Aid | BId | CId | DId | commavalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| raj | 1 | NULL | 0 | 2 | 1,2 |
| ch | 4 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 4,3,1 |

Comment: can we do like this  local-name()="Aid" &   local-name()="BId"  &   local-name()="CId" &   local-name()="DId" because i have10 other columns to remove like Name but Aid and Bid and Cid and Did is fixed four columns. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: also i need to remove null 0 and space value but only check  [text()!="0"]. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: what about null and space condition you are not checking. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: NULLS are omitted automatically. It is mentioned in the notable points.

Comment: if you update null and space condition that means i will update my answer and thanks for your effort for me. @

Comment: if column is empty if you saying null is omitted automatically. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251394/discussion-between-mr-rock-and-yitzhak-khabinsky).

Answer (score 2):

On SQL Server 2014+ we can use the `CONCAT_WS()` function:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',
           CASE WHEN AId != 0 THEN AId END,
           CASE WHEN BId != 0 THEN BId END,
           CASE WHEN CId != 0 THEN CId END,
           CASE WHEN DId != 0 THEN DId END) AS commavalue
FROM yourTable;
```

This trick works because `CONCAT_WS()` does not include null values.  The `CASE` expressions generate null should a particular column be equal to zero.

Using the tip from @ZoharPeled:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', NULLIF(AId, 0), NULLIF(BId, 0), NULLIF(CId, 0),
           NULLIF(DId, 0)) AS commavalue
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: I think concat_ws will not work for my production sql server version can we used using stuff because this will work in all version. @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Your code can be compacted by replacing `case` expressions with `nullif(col, 0)`.

Comment: local version sql: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) and production version Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2). @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Well that's really great news, because my answer should run on both versions.

Comment: The `CONCAT_WS()` function is available starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

Comment: 'CONCAT_WS' is not a recognized built-in function name coming into production. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: can you update your answer CONCAT_WS function will work 2017+ not 2014+ but in my production server 2016 version can you help me by answer using stuff or other logic. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

For old version SQL Server

```
SELECT name
   ,replace(
    replace(
    replace(
        cast(isnull(AId,0) as varchar)+','
       +cast(isnull(BId,0) as varchar)+','
       +cast(isnull(CId,0) as varchar)+','
       +cast(isnull(DId,0) as varchar)
      ,'0,','')
      ,',0','')
      ,'0','')
    AS commavalue
FROM IdList;
```